# Advise right way for bulk adding values to cell depends on other cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, parsing

please advise right way for bulk adding values to cell depends on other cell.
I have csv file and I need to make searching if row in column 1 contains keywords AAA or BBB or CCC then add string XXX to cell in column 3 and string YYY to cell in column 4 in the same row.
If row in column 1 contains keywords DDD or EEE or FFF then add string VVV to cell in column 3 and string WWW to cell in column 4 in the same row.

There is about thousand keyword and they can be different case.

Original csv:

```
1,"AAA 329823 3298","23"
2,"BBB 87682 23423","64"
3,"ccc 73838 72653","45"
4,"DDD 86738 86398","23"
5,"EEE 64833 34322","45"
```

I want:

```
1,"AAA 329823 3298","23",XXX,YYY
2,"BBB 87682 23423","64",XXX,YYY
3,"ccc 73838 72653","45",XXX,YYY
4,"DDD 86738 86398","23","VVV","WWW"
5,"EEE 64833 34322","45","VVV","WWW"
```

Now I use following code but I think it's wrong way:

```
with open(r_file,'r') as csvinput:
    with open(w_file, 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

        all = []

        for row in reader:
            if any(c in row[1] for c in ("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")):
                row.append("XXX")
                row.append("YYY")
            if any(c in row[1] for c in ("DDD", "EEE", "FFF")):
                row.append("VVV")
                row.append("WWW")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for set values by multiple conditions with [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for check substrings:

```
m1 = df[1].str.contains("AAA|BBB|CCC")[:,None]
m2 = df[1].str.contains("DDD|EEE|FFF")[:,None]

df[[3,4]] = pd.DataFrame(np.select([m1, m2], [['XXX','YYY'],['VVV','WWW']], ['','']))
print (df)
   0                1   2    3    4
0  1  AAA 329823 3298  23  XXX  YYY
1  2  BBB 87682 23423  64  XXX  YYY
2  3  ccc 73838 72653  45          
3  4  DDD 86738 86398  23  VVV  WWW
4  5  EEE 64833 34322  45  VVV  WWW
```

**Setup**:

If no header of csv is possible use `header=None` parameter:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u'''1,"AAA 329823 3298","23"
2,"BBB 87682 23423","64"
3,"ccc 73838 72653","45"
4,"DDD 86738 86398","23"
5,"EEE 64833 34322","45"'''
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), header=None)

print (df)

   0                1   2
0  1  AAA 329823 3298  23
1  2  BBB 87682 23423  64
2  3  ccc 73838 72653  45
3  4  DDD 86738 86398  23
4  5  EEE 64833 34322  45
```

EDIT:

```
#setup dictionary
d = {'AAA':['XXX','YYY'], 'BBB':['XXX','YYY'], 'CCC':['XXX','YYY'],
     'DDD':['VVV','WWW'],'EEE':['VVV','WWW'], 'FFF':['VVV','WWW']}

#create DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=['a','b'])
print (df1)
       a    b
AAA  XXX  YYY
BBB  XXX  YYY
CCC  XXX  YYY
DDD  VVV  WWW
EEE  VVV  WWW
FFF  VVV  WWW

#extract valus of dictionary keys to new column
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in d.keys())
df['new'] = df[1].str.extract('(' + pat + ')')
print (df)
   0                1   2  new
0  1  AAA 329823 3298  23  AAA
1  2  BBB 87682 23423  64  BBB
2  3  ccc 73838 72653  45  NaN
3  4  DDD 86738 86398  23  DDD
4  5  EEE 64833 34322  45  EEE

#join df1 by column new
df = df.join(df1, on='new')
print (df)
   0                1   2  new    a    b
0  1  AAA 329823 3298  23  AAA  XXX  YYY
1  2  BBB 87682 23423  64  BBB  XXX  YYY
2  3  ccc 73838 72653  45  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  4  DDD 86738 86398  23  DDD  VVV  WWW
4  5  EEE 64833 34322  45  EEE  VVV  WWW
```

Comment: Yes, I know about it but such way force me write many-many lines for it. I think about something like dictionary

Comment: What is number of sets data like `AAA|BBB|CCC`, `DDD|EEE|FFF` ?

Comment: There are about 1000 such sets

Comment: OK, I add dict solution for you, give me some time.

Comment: @j.stalin - added solution with dictionary